# Conflicting event handlers in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, button, event-handling

I have a page that contains two buttons. I want to use these two buttons to navigate to different pages.

If I just include one of the buttons it works fine. if I include both only one works (as I will show with debug statements if the second button is there, the event handler of the first button is not triggered).

My guess is, that the second button is somehow conflicting with the first button, but I do not know why and how to fix it.

These are some code snippets:

**Backbutton.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click.stop="navigate()"/>
    </div>
</template>
    
<script>
    
    export default {
        name: 'BackButton',
        methods: {
            navigate(){
                console.log("B");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Finishbutton.vue**

```
<template>
    <div :style="visible ? { 'display': 'inline-flex' } : { 'display': 'none' }">
        <button @click.stop="navigate()"/>
    </div>
</template>
    
<script>
 
    export default {
        name: 'FinishButton',
        props : {
            visible: Boolean
        },
        methods: {
            navigate(){
                console.log("F");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Page.vue**

```
<template>
    <BackButton/>
    <FinishButton :visible=ready></FinishButton>
</template>

<script>

import BackButton from "../components/BackButton.vue"
import FinishButton from "../components/FinishButton.vue"

export default {
    name: 'Page',
    components: {
        BackButton,
        FinishButton
    },
    data() {
        return {
            ready: true
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

If `ready` on the page is false (and therefore the `finish-button` is not visible), a click on the `backbutton` prints "B". If `ready` is true, the `finishbutton` prints "F", but clicking on the `backbutton` does not yield any output.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe check your Vue devtools, ESlint, or any console errors, that may indicate some errors aside from my answer. Works flawlessly in a Nuxt2 (Vue2) so far. And probably in a Vue3 too tbh.

Answer (score 0):

There are some minor issues here and there with your code, but the following works well (not sure where exactly this is coming from tho).

`Page.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <BackButton></BackButton>
    <FinishButton :visible="ready"></FinishButton>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BackButton from '../components/BackButton.vue'
import FinishButton from '../components/FinishButton.vue'

export default {
  name: 'Page',
  components: {
    BackButton,
    FinishButton,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      ready: true,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

`BackButton.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click.stop="navigate">back</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'BackButton',
  methods: {
    navigate() {
      console.log('B')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

`FinishButton.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div :style="visible ? { display: 'inline-flex' } : { display: 'none' }">
    <button @click.stop="navigate">finish</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'FinishButton',
  props: {
    visible: Boolean,
  },
  methods: {
    navigate() {
      console.log('F')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

---

Or at least, I cannot reproduce your issue with the provided snippet.